# Merging Dataframes that was obtained via web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that scrapes tables from a website, and reads it into pandas Dataframe. However, this is done through a `for` loop because of how the website has been designed. As such, the tables are all tagged with the same `name` ie: they are tagged under `df` name

**Code**

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    for thead in soup.select(".data-point-container table thead"):
        tbody = thead.find_next_sibling("tbody")

        table = "<table>%s</table>" % (str(thead) + str(tbody))

        df = pandas.read_html(str(table))[0]

        print(df)
        print('-------------')
```

**Result**

```
     Table1   FY2012   FY2013   FY2014   FY2015   Last 12 Months
0    item1    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
1    item2    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
2    item3    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
3    item4    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
4    item5    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
5    item6    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
-------------

     Table2   FY2012   FY2013   FY2014   FY2015   Last 12 Months
0    item1    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
1    item2    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
2    item3    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
3    item4    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
-------------

     Table3   FY2012   FY2013   FY2014   FY2015   Last 12 Months
0    item1    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
1    item2    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
2    item3    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
3    item4    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
4    item5    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
5    item6    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
-------------

     Table4   FY2012   FY2013   FY2014   FY2015   Last 12 Months
0    item1    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
1    item2    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
2    item3    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
3    item4    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
4    item5    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
5    item6    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
6    item7    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
7    item8    value1   value2   value3   value4   value5
```

Is there a way for me to concat / merge all Dataframes together into just 1 Dataframe?

Comment: Again, there are quite a lot of questions that cater to merging of DataFrames. And we would like to see what you have tried and what makes this problem significantly different from the others already on this site. As a consolation, try taking a look at the Pandas merging documentation.

Comment: Again.. I'm asking for ideas. As a consolation, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is merge a number of DataFrames, you can simply collect them in a list and then merge them using [pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Something like this should work:

```
dataframes = []

for thread in soup.select(...):

    #your scraper logic here

    df = pandas.read_html(...)
    dataframes.append(df)

pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Does that help?