# pandas update dataframe values if cell contains '-'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe which has 46 columns, and 6 rows.

```
Index    Column1    Column2    Column3   Column4      ... # Cant type all 46 columns.
2012     5626       fooo       -         barrr
2013     5655h      booo       -         barr
2014     5626d      zooo       -         -
LTM      56         gooo       greed     -
```

Is there a way for me to go through this Dataframe and update all the `-` values to be `0` or `null` values?

I have tried:

```
for zzz in df.columns:  # since df.columns will return me the names of the columns
    if df_final[zzz].any() == '-':
        df_final[zzz] = 0
        print(df_final)
```

However, this just prints everything out as it is. it does not convert `-` into `0 / null`

Comment: Even if your code would work, it's the wrong semantics as it would've updated the entire column to `0`, also you failed to show what `df_final` is in your code snippet

Comment: @jake, Suggestion: avoid using loops. Avoid coding your DataFrames to work in loops, that will not get you results. Python has a different way of handling names, and things are not mutable from anywhere. And Pandas almost always returns a copy, so any changes will not affect the parent. Use the DataFrame methods. Read the pandas docs on how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace that specific value with another one:

```
In [71]:
df.replace('-',0, inplace=True)
df

Out[71]:
  Index Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0  2012    5626    fooo       0   barrr
1  2013   5655h    booo       0    barr
2  2014   5626d    zooo       0       0
3   LTM      56    gooo   greed       0
```

Your code even if it would've worked is the wrong semantics:

```
for zzz in df.columns: 
    if df_final[zzz].any() == '-':
        df_final[zzz] = 0
        print(df_final)
```

this: `df_final[zzz] = 0` would've updated the entire column

if your code was:

```
for zzz in df.columns: 
    if df_final[zzz].any() == '-':
        df_final[zzz] = df_final[zzz].replace('-',0)
        print(df_final)
```

then this would've only replace the rows that met the condition, you could've also done:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('-',0))
```

for a more compact method

**EDIT** if you want to replace with `NaN` then pass `np.NaN` instead of `0` above.

Comment: He probably wants to replace it with `np.nan` based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845435/can-i-create-a-loop-to-update-sql-database Basically, it appears that he has to build an entire data processing pipeline right from scraping data from a web server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810575/merging-dataframes-that-was-obtained-via-web-scraping to inserting the resulting DataFrame into a SQL DB...

Comment: @Kartik yes answer, sorry auto typing responses without reading

Comment: @Ed, its amazing how you guys can do that even with code. By the time it takes me to understand and formulate an answer, there already is an answer from someone with rep over 10k... I guess it is just lots of practice...

Comment: Thanks EdChum, this is comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
print (df.replace({'-': 0}))
  Index Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0  2012    5626    fooo       0   barrr
1  2013   5655h    booo       0    barr
2  2014   5626d    zooo       0       0
3   LTM      56    gooo   greed       0
```

Comment: I'm curious. If lets say `Column1` values are in a bracket, eg: `(5626)`. Will I be able to use the `.replace` function to change it to `-5626` instead?

Comment: I think yes. the best is use small sample Dataframe and test it - e.g. use `df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['(5626)','aa',''],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})`